# How to align elements in header

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so my HTML element doesn't` push down my other elements.

Here is my header:
[image: header]

The BitBay title is pushing down the search bar, I would like it aligned with the text, so it doesn't look awkward.

If you look closely, you can see the account button is pushed a bit too.

I have tried using the text-align property with no luck. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "mindex.html"; //Mobile site
  }
  //-->
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>BitBay</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" href="IMG/Logo.jpg">
<div id="header">
<a href="index.html"><h1>BitBay</h1></a>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>Account</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="account.html"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>Login</a>
    <a href="signup.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Signup</a>
    <a href="help.html"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>Help & Support</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<noscript>
    <div class="noscriptmsg">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=javascript.html">
    </div>
</noscript>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
#header input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 21%;
    margin-bottom: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}

/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */
#header input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 17%;
}

/*Header Text*/
#header h1 {
    font-family: "smooth";
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 0;
}

/* Make unordered list horizontle */
#header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: -12.5px;
    margin-left: 270px;
}

/* Make unordered list horizontle */
#header ul li {
    display: inline;
}

/* Make boxed & colored */
#header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2% 3%;
    color: #FFF; /*Text color, when not hovered*/
}

/* Make change colors, when hovered on */
#header ul li a:hover{
    color: lightgray; /*Text color*/
}

/* Header box */
#header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #3385ff;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*Remove line*/
#header a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: wow, you put html in <head> tag?

Comment: don't mix up `<head>` and `<header>` tags: `<head>` doesn't contain anything that is shown on the page, but just links to external stylesheets, meta information, scripts etc.....

Comment: You can see where it starts under <div id="header">, and below all the CSS properties I have for that.

Comment: To fix the most basic error in there, move your closing `</head>` tag ABOVE the opening `<div id="header">` tag. It has nothing to do with your problem, but it's the first step to valid HTML

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to use divs to contain each element that is inside your header, this might help you solve the issue, for example your anchor and input are not contained inside a div, and add css to these divs not to the input or anchor element.

Don't forget to check the display value of each div or element.